# Cloud watch query for message like list of strings

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Am using a query to search the messages like 'string' using below

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /engineer/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

wants to search message contains any of the strings in a list and tried the below query but, its not working. Am getting the results which does not contain those values.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /[engineer|doctor|builder]/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Intention is to get logs which contains engineer OR doctor OR builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
filter @message like /(engineer|builder|doctor)/
```

Using the square brackets will match individual characters, `[doctor]` matches something like `(d|o|c|t|o|r)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation to understand it along with the example

Comment: To add onto this you can also use named capturing groups to extract fields based on the regex. For example: parse @message /(?<fieldName>engineer|doctor)/